# Only Some Columns of Table Display after Added to Array in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get all columns and rows to appear after being added to an array in JS and PHP.  For some reason, neither the player column nor the status column are filled with content.  Any insight into this is appreciated.

This is the code where the array is collected:

```php
<?php include('../../functions.php');

    $query = "
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    plobby
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.UID = plobby.UID
    WHERE
    `LID` = '". preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $_POST['id']) ."';
    ";

    $result = $db->query($query);

    $rows = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

And this is the code where the table originates:

```js
var reloadTable = function(data) {
  if ($.data(state) == $.data(data)) {
    return;
  }

  $('#js-lobby-table').empty();

  $.each(data, function(rowNumber, rowData) {

    var row = $('<tr>');

    //console.log(data);

    // Player
    row.append($('<td>', {
      'html': data.eName
    }));

    // Status
    row.append($('<td>', {
      'html': data.gameID == "000" ? 'waiting' : 'ingame'
    }));

    // Win %
    row.append($('<td>', {
      'html': 'TODO'
    }));

    // Games
    row.append($('<td>', {
      'html': 'TODO'
    }));

    // K/D
    row.append($('<td>', {
      'html': 'TODO'
    }));

    $('#js-lobby-table').append(row);
  });

  // Set the current table state.
  state = data;
};

setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/lobby/api/table.php',
    data: {
      id: '<?= $_GET['
      id '] ?>'
    },
    success: reloadTable,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you debug, look at the values in your variables to ensure they are what you expect them to be.  Your code is treating these variables inconsistently.  For example, you're looping over `data`:

```
$.each(data ...
```

Which implies that `data` is an array.  But then you also try to access values on `data`:

```
'html': data.eName
```

I *suspect* that you actually want to access values on `rowData` within that iteration:

```
'html': rowData.eName
```

(Same error a few more lines down in your code.)